# Corrections to plasmons theory. (History of Plasmons)

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics, history, plasmon

Is it true that around 70's there was a huge change in theory that describes plasmons (SPP, to be precise)? Recently I stumbled upon an interesting (but old) [paper about plasmons](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0039602886900567). Authors of that paper reported something like "resonance obtained by us occurs at different angle than it should be theoretically and we don't know the reason for that".

When I asked my coworkers about their remarks, they had no idea what that could be, but one of them told me that around 70's or 80's there were some changes in the theory and the experimental results from before that reform may be inconsistent with theory.

Can you tell me when were the most significant changes introduced in past decades?

Answer (score 3):

Some aspects of SPP theory have remained the same over the years (e.g. the basic dispersion relation of an SPP at the metal-dielectric interface).  But from your linked paper, it seems that you may be interested in SPP excitation via the Kretschmann-Raether configuration.  In this area, I would say there has been some recent development in understanding; check out [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep09929.pdf).  I'm not sure about what happened 40 years ago, though.

Comment: (but I will wait with approving your answer, to see if someone else says something else)

Comment: @user46147 good call.